# Install Anaconda not enough on menu

Tags: python-3.x

I install python 3.6 ( from anaconda.com) for win 7,64bit, relocated on D:\
I also check on Add path tick box.

But after installed, from Menu I just see Anaconda Prompt, don't have Jupyter, Spyder

Comment: Are you trying to look for the executables for Spyder (and/or Jupyter)? While I cannot help you with Jupyter, since I rarely use it myself, the spyder executable is located under `InstallFolder\Anaconda3\pkgs\spyder-{VERSION}\Scripts\spyder.exe`. Similarly, there is a folder called Jupyter, but you'd have to figure out yourself whether it contains the right executables.

Comment: But I can't find this file in folder Scripts

Comment: I try to install and uninstall many times, locate default and also relocate (D:\), but it's still not enough, just having anaconda prompt and python found.

Comment: Can you share what happens if you try to run `conda install spyder` from an (adminstrator) console? And can you verify that you are not just installing Miniconda, but the full installation?